# Querying polygons that lie inside 4 points

Tags: postgis, gdal, postgresql, ogr

I have 4 points that I always get, I would like to query if the polygon in the multipoint lies inside those 4 points. I’m using PostGIS, PostgreSQL.

I Have 4 Points which are dynamically updated I would like to query all the polgyons that lie inside those 4 points.

My Polgyon points are:

```
x = 16.07514381, double y = 47.95055008;
x = 16.24965286, y = 47.91411209;
x = 16.23201180, y = 47.82641983;
x = 16.14973259, y = 47.79749298;
x = 15.93255901, y = 47.89419937;
```

here is what I did so far

```
SELECT gid
FROM areas
WHERE st_contains(
         st_polygon(
            st_linefrommultipoint(
               areas.geom
            ),
            0
         ),
         st_mpointfromtext(
            'MULTIPOINT(1 1, 2 2, 3 3, 4 4)'
         )
      );
```

Comment: Polygons *can't* "lie inside" points -- Polygons could **contain** points, or points couls be **within** polygons. It's also possible for each to **intersect** the other. Please [edit] the question to contain the proper relationship, to specify the exact versions of PostgreSQL and PostGIS, and to contain the SQL you have tried (with the results or error). A screenshot or image might help clarify your problem.

Comment: so I need polygons that contain those 4 points. I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6 and PostGIS 2.3

Comment: @Vince Note that I'm using GDAl 2.1 ogr. so I have to use a query that is supported by it

Comment: Please **edit the question** to contain information requested in comments. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.  You stll need to provide a good-faith effort for performing the query with your interface of choice (which isn't mentioned in the question)

Comment: As per your other (now deleted) question, It is not clear what you are asking.  Please **[edit]** your question to clarify what you are trying to do, and what you have tried.  Add a picture of your points and draw an example of how you wish your query to select your points.  You can add screenshots when editing your question by clicking the Image button above the edit box.   Please don't just delete and re-ask questions, as this loses the history of any comments and clarifications of previous questions - rather edit and improve your question in order to get it reopened and answered

Comment: @Midavalo I have clarified the post, please take a look, thanks for feedback

Answer (score -1):

You could try to use something like this:

```
ST_Contains(polygon.geom,ST_ConvexHull(4points.geom))
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm beginner, I can get the geometry from the column GEOM. How would I set it in the above SQL statement, I also want to select "All" polygons " from the table not only one polygon

Comment: and the 4points will be define inside the code from example
 string query = "ST_Contains(polygon.geom,ST_ConvexHull(4points.geom))";